# Help in a proof of a proposition in Conway's complex analysis book

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and I didn't understand the proof of this proposition on page 59:

> **Proposition.** If $\gamma:[a,b]\to \mathbb C$ is a piecewise smooth then $\gamma$ is of bounded variation and
>   $$V(\gamma)=\int_a^b|\gamma'(t)|dt$$

The proof:

[image]

Why are these two implications true?

Comment: The first underlined section follows from the definition of the Riemann integral : $\lim_{\|\mathcal{P}\|\rightarrow 0}\sum_{\mathcal{P}}|\gamma'(t_k)|\Delta t_k = \int_{a}^{b}|\gamma'(t)|dt$.

Comment: The second follows from the uniform continuity of $\gamma'$ on an interval; you can reduce to this case because $\gamma'$ is assumed to be piecewise continuous.

Comment: @TrialAndError thank you! do you know where can I find this definition of integral? thank you again!

Comment: The Riemann integral is usually discussed in Calculus. For sure it would be discussed in Advanced Calculus.

Comment: @TrialAndError Yes I know, but the definition I know is the sup of inferior sums (it can defined as the inf of superior sums as well). I think this is the definition used in Rudin's analysis book.

Comment: You can use that definition to get what you want, too. Keep in mind that $|\gamma'(t)|$ is a real function. The integral is arbitrarily well-approximated by a sum.